# Closing tabs in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I often have many tabs open and when I closed a tab it would automatically move on to the next tab along. Recently Chrome goes to the last open tab at the end of the row rather than next tab along. How can I get my pc to go back to going to the next open tab?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Consider [taking a tour](https://superuser.com/tour), and also [how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). Could you be more specific on which OS and version of Chrome you are using? Also, have this behavior started after an update? Please edit your question with more information.

Comment: The default close order would be the inverse of the opening order. If you have a restored session, then the opening order is quite likely to be different to what it was initially - left to right would seem an obvious method. Try it with a brand new window with tabs in a known order.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, it worked, :)

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to replicate the same issue.

You may try visiting chrome://settings/appearance, clicking on 'advanced' and restore chrome settings.

[Reset screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwy3M.png)

Do read the text before clicking 'Reset settings'

Comment: I'm working tonight, but I will try that when I have finished, thank you for your response.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, it worked, :)